# Shortcodes attributes not working out of page/post editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme settings page with a wysiwyg editor. I want to use shortcodes with attributes inside.

This is one of the shortcodes with attributes, to use as example:

```
function row( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract(shortcode_atts(
    array(
    'paddingtop' => 'PADDINGTOP',
    ), $atts )
  );
  return '<div class="row" style="padding-top:'.$paddingtop.';"></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'fila', 'row');
```

Here I add the wysiwyg editor to my theme settings page:

```
array(
  'name'  => '',
  'id'    => 'editor_top_shop',
  'type'  => 'editor',
  'note'  => '',
),
```

This is how I check and print the content in the editor:

```
<?php if ( get_option( 'editor_top_shop' ) == true ) {

    $top_shop = get_option( 'editor_top_shop' );
    echo stripslashes(apply_filters("the_content", $top_shop));

<?php } ?>
```

Shortcode in the editor:

```
[fila paddingtop="40px"]
```

And finally, this is the HTML output:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:PADDINGTOP;"></div>
```

I would appreciate some feedback, I am getting mad about this :(

Thank you very much!
Frede

Comment: whats in $atts and $content variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a solution :)

As you said @Poiz, almost all code was OK, but I made a little change at the time to print. Here the solution:

```
$top_shop = get_option( 'ace_top_shop' );
$top_shop = stripslashes($top_shop);
echo (apply_filters("the_content", $top_shop));
```

I've got to stripleashes separately instead of doing all the same time. Don't know why...BUT IT WORKS! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is clean... and I also don't see why this should be the result except if you have a typo in the name of the short-code attribute. Meanwhile, try to set the paddingtop attribute to a default of 40px instead of "PADDINGTOP". And then experiment with changing the values of the Attributes.

```
    <?php
        function row( $atts, $content = null ) {
            extract(shortcode_atts(
                    array(
                        'paddingtop' => '40px', /*<== DOESN'T MATTER BUT TRY DEFAULTING THIS TO 40px */
                    ), $atts )
            );
            return '<div class="row" style="padding-top:'. $paddingtop .';"></div>';
        }
        add_shortcode( 'fila', 'row');
```

Another Approach could be to drop the extract function (since you have only one attribute to deal with) and do the extraction manually yourself like so:

```
        function row( $atts, $content = null ) {
            $paddingTop   = isset($atts['paddingtop']) ? $atts['paddingtop'] : "40px";
            return '<div class="row" style="padding-top:'. $paddingTop .';"></div>';
        }
        add_shortcode( 'fila', 'row');
```

Comment: Thank you Poiz, there is not a typo mistake, I made double check. If I set a default value like 40px it will work, but it needs to be able to change it.

BTW, dropping extract functions wouldn´t work. I have a lot of shortcodes with multiple attributes and all have the same problem.

Comment: @FredericGarcia   Exactly, that is the goal: to be able to change the value within the short-code using your attributes. Have you tried the 2nd alternative? You may then change the padding top to 80px to see if it is reflected in your result.

Comment: Sorry Poiz I missunderstood. I just did that, and now I get the default value instead of the value in the text editor.

Comment: @FredericGarcia   Since you have a lot of Short-Code with the same Problem, then it is clear (like i already said) that your codes are clean. The Trouble, then, should be somewhere else. It is certainly not in the code you showed us here because I see nothing wrong with it. Expectedly, it should have worked normally. From what you are saying, the point is that the $atts are not being passed properly to the shortcodes.